# Is it possible to implement row-level security in MonetDB?

Tags: security, monetdb

I'd like to use MonetDB for analytic reports on big data sets that automatically triggers requirements to have row-level security (RLS) based on user provision.
I attempted to use views with functions but MonetDB still requires the same user provision to underlying tables.
MySQL/PostgreSQL offers at least some RLS options. What are the options to achieve RLS in MonetDB if any?
Are there any plans to expand product features if it is not possible in current versions?

Comment: MonetDB currently doesn't support RLS but adding something similar to what Postgres does, i.e. having a per-user policy which does a select on the data should be possible.

It's probably best to directly contact the MonetDB team to discuss the details. This question here is too general to give further answers.

Comment: Jennie 
I noticed one enhancement for GRANT on views where grant can be applied to the view only (More tests for GRANT SELECT on <view>)
It looks like latest Oct2020-SP2 version  does not support it and I am getting SQL Error [42000]: SELECT: access denied for <user> to table '<table>'.
Will it be available in the next release?

Comment: Yes, it's a new feature, hence, not included in an SP release for Oct2020, but it's finished, so it'll be included in the coming feature release.  We don't know for sure when the first feature release of 2021 will be, but I estimate H1/2021.